# How to debug AWS auto scalling issue?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I have a application on AWS with auto scaling setup. Based on the auto scaling configuration , instance adding/terminating automatically.

When terminating instance one by one and the last instance health going to red . It works only when i deploy manually.

**Example:**
I have A,B,C instance running, A and B terminated. Now C instance health going to red, and i deploy it manually after that C instance works well.

How to debug this problem?. is there any configuration issue?

Comment: Are you referring to ELB healthcheck or AutoScaling healthcheck ? Something is probably wrong in your bootstrapping procedure. How do you configure the instances ? (user-data, chef, puppet, custom AMI,... ?)

Comment: H, thanks for the reply. I am referring ELB healthcheck. Now i am access AWS throw web url (console.aws.amazon.com). I dont understand what is bootstrapping procedure.

Comment: Bootstrapping is the dynamic configuration of your instances when they are started as part of an autoscaling group.  How do you get your software installed on these machine ?  Are you using a custom AMI ?  A standard AWS provided AMI and custom scripts ?  other (like Chef or Puppet?)  If you ELB healthcheck is returning "unhealthy" status, this means that your application is not correctly deployed to your instances or you ELB healthcheck URL is not valid.

Comment: thanks for the rply. I am installing varnish cache and apc by .ebextensions. I will stop both and test.